# Find the highest column of each worksheet

Tags: php, phpexcel

Is there a way to get the highest column value for example the highest column that contains values. using getWorksheetIterator. I want to get the column and use that to clean cells upto the highest column.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A simple call to the getHighestDataColumn() method for the worksheet should give you this